# django ajax запрос undefined

Tags: python, ajax, django, веб-программирование

у меня есть ajax запрос:

```
<script>
function valid(form)
{
    name = $('#id_name').value;
    password = $('#id_password').value;
    repassword = $('#id_repassword').value;
    $.ajax({
        url:'/javascript/',
        method:'POST',
        data:{'name':name, 'password':password, 'repassword':repassword,'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
        success: function(data){alert("Success!")}
    });
}
</script>
```

вот html:

```
<label for="id_name">Имя: </label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="id_name" placeholder="Имя..."><br>
<label for="id_password">Пароль: </label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" placeholder="Пароль..."><br>
<label for="id_repassword">Повторите пароль: </label>
<input type="password" name="repassword" id="id_repassword" placeholder="Повторите пароль..."><br>
<input type="button" id="id_button" name="button" onclick="valid()">
```

вот обработчик на django:

```
def javascript(request):
    if request.POST:
        name = request.POST['name']
        print(name)
        return HttpResponse('/')
    else:
        print("First")
        return render(request, 'javascript.html', {'title':'javascript'});
```

все все работает, но место имени которое я ввожу, выводится в консоль undefined

Вроде бы все верно(

Скажите что не так!

Comment: + alert("Success!") срабатывает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не верно:

```
name = $('#id_name').value;
password = $('#id_password').value;
repassword = $('#id_repassword').value;
```

Должно быть вот так:

```
name = $('#id_name').val();
password = $('#id_password').val();
repassword = $('#id_repassword').val();
```